# in VBA Excel 2013 how do I make the FullSeriesCollection(1).XValues and Values point to an array?

Tags: excel, vba, charts, series

I can make the X and Y data for a scatter chart a range, but cannot point the series data to an array. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

It is possible. You might want to check out these links: [Series.XValues](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff821866.aspx), [Series.Values](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff197014.aspx).

**XValues**:

> Returns or sets an array of x values for a chart series. The XValues property can be set to a range on a worksheet or to an array of values, but it cannot be a combination of both. Read/write Variant.

```
Charts("Chart1").SeriesCollection(1).XValues = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B1:B5")
```

Or

```
Charts("Chart1").SeriesCollection(1).XValues = Array(5.0, 6.3, 12.6, 28, 50)
```

**Values**:

> Returns or sets a Variant value that represents a collection of all the values in the series.

```
Charts("Chart1").SeriesCollection(1).Values = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("C5:T5")
```

Or

```
Charts("Chart1").SeriesCollection(1).Values = Array(1, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19)
```

Comment: I want to point the Xvalues and Values to existing two single dimension arrays. I have called them "xarr" and "yarr". Do I just put the array name after the = sign or put it in quotation marks?

Comment: Just use `.XValues = xarr` and/or `.Values = yarr`.

Comment: Thanks, it's obvious when you put it this way!  Thanks again.